minidump control for .Net MAUI not working
I want to control the minidump size for my .Net MAUI program. According to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/collect-dumps-crash#types-of-mini-dumps , I tried set DOTNET_DbgMiniDumpType in program using "Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable", or directly in command line, then create a simple crash like this:
     string? str = null;
     Console.WriteLine( str.Length ); // NullReferenceException

All tests are under win11, VS2022 17.10, sample MAUI helloworld program.
But, the dmp file created under CrashDumps folder are always 580MB+, nearly the same size.
Anybody can give me some advice?

Did you try to set it to the other value such as Full and then check the size of the CrashDumps folder.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes, I tried, but every options seems the same result. I think there's something wrong in my way to set this.

Could you share the code about how you set the environment variable? Did the DOTNET_DbgMiniDumpType successfully set?

@LiqunShen-MSFT I set them directly in "Windows - Environment Variables - System Variables"。 Does this work? I'm using .Net 8.0

Update: On another win11 computer, fire exceptions in main thread doesn't generate .dmp in %LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps. Then I set COMPlus_DbgEnableMiniDump /DOTNET_DbgEnableMiniDump to 1 in "Windows - Environment Variables - System Variables",  still no dmp generated.

You mean on one computer it generated dmp file while on another computer it didn't. Any difference between the two scenarios?

@LiqunShen-MSFT well the two computer has lot of differences, one is company domain controlled, one is my personal. But they both win11 23R2, with VS installed. That's not the point. I need to know why DOTNET_XXXX flags not working? is there any working samples for these flags?

You may try setting <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun> in your  .csproj file and generate and see if that makes any difference in the dump size?

Setting <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>  then  the app is not AOT'd.

Here's my test routine:
1, create a sample MAUI program which will case NullReferenceException when click button, by .NET 8
2, Add         false  under 
3, Rebuild the project
4, Set COMPlus_DbgMiniDumpType to 1 in both "User variables" and "System Variables" in Windows 11 "Environment Variables" page.
5, Run the app, click button to invoke exception.
6, Check %localappdata%\crashdumps
7, the dump size not changed.
@LiqunShen-MSFT

Have you tried setting CustomDumpFlags to control the dump size?

From the Types of mini dumps you posted in your question, I saw this,

Only full dumps are supported by the single-file and Native AOT app models.

So what about MAUI windows?  Is it an AOT app model?
See here ReadyToRun by Default on Windows,

R2R is form of ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation...

So I think in .NET8 Maui on Windows is an AOT app model.  That's the reason why we are always getting full dumps for MAUI windows.
For more info, you may refer to ReadyToRun Compilation.
